# Stored Procedure Not Working, depending upon parameter values passed

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have SP to update data in my DB..
my Stored Procedure like This :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updatesms] @KodeTingkat INT,
        @KodeKel INT,
        @KodeTPS INT,
        @SuaraPartai INT,
        @KodeCaleg1 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg1 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg2 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg2 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg3 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg3 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg4 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg4 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg5 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg5 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg6 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg6 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg7 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg7 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg8 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg8 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg9 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg9 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg10 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg10 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg11 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg11 INT = -1
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT Id
            FROM Kelurahans
            WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat

        UPDATE TPSSet 
            SET SuaraPartai=@SuaraPartai
            WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel 
                AND TPSS = @KodeTPS

        IF @KodeCaleg1 > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT Id
                    FROM Kelurahans
                    WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
                UPDATE Calegs
                    SET JumlahPerolehan = @SuaraCaleg1
                    WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg1
                        AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                            SELECT id 
                            FROM TPSSet
                            WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS )
            END

        IF @KodeCaleg2 > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT Id
                    FROM Kelurahans
                    WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
                UPDATE Calegs
                    SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg2
                    WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg2
                        AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                            SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                            WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS )
            END

        IF @KodeCaleg3 > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT Id
                    FROM Kelurahans
                    WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
                UPDATE Calegs
                    SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg3
                    WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg3
                        AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                            SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                            WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS )
            END

        IF @KodeCaleg4 > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT Id
                    FROM Kelurahans
                    WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
                UPDATE Calegs
                    SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg4
                    WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg4
                        AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                            SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                            WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS )
            END

        IF @KodeCaleg5 > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT Id
                    FROM Kelurahans
                    WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
                UPDATE Calegs
                    SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg5
                    WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg5
                        AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                            SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                            WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS )
           END

        IF @KodeCaleg6 > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT Id
                    FROM Kelurahans
                    WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
                UPDATE Calegs
                    SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg6
                    WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg6
                        AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                            SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                            WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS )
            END

        IF @KodeCaleg7 > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT Id
                    FROM Kelurahans
                    WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
                UPDATE Calegs
                    SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg7
                    WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg7
                        AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                            SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                            WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS )
            END

        IF @KodeCaleg8 > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT Id
                    FROM Kelurahans
                    WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
                UPDATE Calegs
                    SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg8
                    WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg8
                        AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                            SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                            WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS )
            END    

        IF @KodeCaleg9 > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT Id
                    FROM Kelurahans
                    WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
                UPDATE Calegs
                    SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg9
                    WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg9
                        AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                            SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                            WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS )
            END

        IF @KodeCaleg10 > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT Id
                    FROM Kelurahans
                    WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
                UPDATE Calegs
                    SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg10
                    WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg10
                        AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                            SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                            WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS )
            END    

        IF @KodeCaleg11 > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT Id
                    FROM Kelurahans
                    WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
                UPDATE Calegs
                    SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg11
                    WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg11
                        AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                            SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                            WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS )
            END            
    END
```

---

My Question :
if SET @KodeTingkat=1 Stored procedure working to update SuaraPartai, @SuaraCaleg1, @SuaraCaleg2 until @SuaraCaleg11

if SET @KodeTingkat=2 or SET @KodeTingkat=3 a stored procedure not working to update above..
so, please help..

I use this command to call a function stored procedure updates:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
EXEC updatesms 1,1,1,300,1,80,2,30,3,70,4,50,5,60,6,50,7,25,8,800 
COMMIT
```

description:

1. number 1 on the first letter .. so, when I put the number 1 on the first character, fed automatically be selected code = 1 in Table tingkatans
2. number 1 on the second letter .. it will automatically chosen code in table 1 kelurahans
3. number 1 on the third letter .. when code = 1 tingkatans tables and code = 1 kelurahans selected in the table and code = 1 TPSSet table, it will automatically renew / update SuaraPartai denganjumlah 300 on letters 4
4. number 1 on the letters to the fifth, meaning I choose code = 1 in table Calegs
5. number 80 on the letters to six, meaning that I do an update JumlahPerolehan = 80, code = 1 in table Calegs
6. same as point five

This My schema relation :

[image: http://imgur.com/mKAwD1x]

### ***UPDATE:***

Using the code from the answer, below, to test execute outside the stored procedure... 
the code that begins like this:

```
------    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updatesms]

DECLARE
        @KodeTingkat INT,
        @KodeKel INT,
        @KodeTPS INT,
        @SuaraPartai INT,
        @KodeCaleg1 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg1 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg2 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg2 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg3 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg3 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg4 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg4 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg5 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg5 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg6 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg6 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg7 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg7 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg8 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg8 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg9 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg9 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg10 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg10 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg11 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg11 INT = -1

------        AS


SET @KodeTingkat=1 
----SET @KodeTingkat=2 
----SET @KodeTingkat=3 

SET @KodeKel=1
SET @KodeTPS=1
SET @SuaraPartai=300
SET @KodeCaleg1=1
SET @SuaraCaleg1=80
SET @KodeCaleg2=2
SET @SuaraCaleg2=30
SET @KodeCaleg3=3
SET @SuaraCaleg3=70
SET @KodeCaleg4=4
SET @SuaraCaleg4=50
SET @KodeCaleg5=5
SET @SuaraCaleg5=60
SET @KodeCaleg6=6
SET @SuaraCaleg6=50
SET @KodeCaleg7=7
SET @SuaraCaleg7=25
SET @KodeCaleg8=8
SET @SuaraCaleg8=800 

BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        -- suara partai
        DECLARE @Kelurahans_ID INT

        SELECT @Kelurahans_ID = Id
        FROM Kelurahans
        WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
        ;
        PRINT 'A)  @Kelurahans_ID is set to ' + STR(@Kelurahans_ID) + ', reading ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'

        UPDATE TPSSet SET SuaraPartai=@SuaraPartai
        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS
        ;
        PRINT 'B)  SuaraPartai is set to ' + STR(@SuaraPartai) + ', reading ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'

        -- suara caleg 1
        IF @KodeCaleg1 > 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'C)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg1, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg1) 
                ;
                UPDATE Calegs
                SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg1
                WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg1
                AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                        SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID
                )
                ;
                PRINT 'D)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg1, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg1) + '; processing ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'
        END
        -- suara caleg 2
.
.
.
```

And with that code, here's example output, if I set @KodeTingkat = 1

- A)  @Kelurahans_ID is set to          1, reading          1 rows.
- B)  SuaraPartai is set to        300, reading          1 rows.
- C)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg1, which =         1
- D)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg1, which =          1;
  processing          1 rows.
- E)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg2, which =         2
- F)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg2, which =          2;
  processing          1 rows.
- G)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg3, which =         3
- H)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg3, which =          3;
  processing          1 rows.
- I)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg4, which =         4
- J)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg4, which =          4;
  processing          1 rows.
- K)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg5, which =         5
- L)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg5, which =          5;
  processing          1 rows.
- M)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg6, which =         6
- N)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg6, which =          6;
  processing          1 rows.
- O)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg7, which =         7
- P)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg7, which =          7;
  processing          1 rows.
- Q)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg8, which =         8
- R)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg8, which =          8;
  processing          1 rows.
- S)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg9, which =         9
- T)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg9, which =          9;
  processing          1 rows.
- U)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg10, which =        10
- V)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg10, which =         10;
  processing          1 rows.
- W)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg11, which =        11
- X)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg11, which =         11;
  processing          1 rows.
- Affected rows: 0
- Time: 0.097s

(Note: `...processing 1 rows` is repeated)

### **So, with @KodeTingkat = 1, the code *updates* rows...**

Now here's example output, if I set @KodeTingkat = 2

- A)  @Kelurahans_ID is set to          2, reading          1 rows.
- B)  SuaraPartai is set to        200, reading          1 rows.
- C)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg1, which =         1
- D)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg1, which =          1;
  processing          0 rows.
- E)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg2, which =         2
- F)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg2, which =          2;
  processing          0 rows.
- G)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg3, which =         3
- H)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg3, which =          3;
  processing          0 rows.
- I)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg4, which =         4
- J)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg4, which =          4;
  processing          0 rows.
- K)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg5, which =         5
- L)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg5, which =          5;
  processing          0 rows.
- M)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg6, which =         6
- N)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg6, which =          6;
  processing          0 rows.
- O)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg7, which =         7
- P)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg7, which =          7;
  processing          0 rows.
- Q)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg8, which =         8
- R)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg8, which =          8;
  processing          0 rows.
- S)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg9, which =         9
- T)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg9, which =          9;
  processing          0 rows.
- U)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg10, which =        10
- V)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg10, which =         10;
  processing          0 rows.
- W)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg11, which =        11
- X)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg11, which =         11;
  processing          0 rows.
- Affected rows: 0
- Time: 0.054s

(Note: `...processing 0 rows` is repeated)

### **So, with @KodeTingkat = 2, the code does *not* update rows...**

### **Why?**

Comment: define "SP working" and "SP not working".  remember no one here understands your business logic or even has any idea what your code is supposed to do.  you have no comments and your variables names will mean nothing to all the English speakers.

Comment: sory my bad, i'have update quetion..

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) applies to you just as well.

Comment: What isn't working? What is being returned? What did you expect? Do you have sample data for anyone to look at? Like posted above, a long list of code won't do anything to make it possible for anyone to assist you.

Comment: You need to include `EXECUTE dbo.updatesms` samples that produce correct results vs the ones that don't. You should use [`PRINT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) statements to debug your SP.

Comment: I have renewed the question specifically

Comment: Part of your problem is trying to send a list of integers and hoping they will match to correct parameters. You should always explicitly specify each parameter and value that you are passing.

Comment: when I enter the number 1 in the first letter, the stored procedure runs fine .. 
but when I enter the number 2 or 3 on the first letter, the stored procedure does not run

Comment: You define *26 parameters*, but your `EXEC` command only specifies values for *20 parameters*.  Was that intentional?  Using @VladimirOselsky's **GOOD IDEA**, your command would be:  `BEGIN TRANSACTION EXEC updatesms@KodeTingkat=1, @KodeKel=1, @KodeTPS=1, @SuaraPartai=300, @KodeCaleg1=1, @SuaraCaleg1=80, @KodeCaleg2=2, @SuaraCaleg2=30, @KodeCaleg3=3, @SuaraCaleg3=70, @KodeCaleg4=4, @SuaraCaleg4=50, @KodeCaleg5=5, @SuaraCaleg5=60, @KodeCaleg6=6, @SuaraCaleg6=50, @KodeCaleg7=7, @SuaraCaleg7=25, @KodeCaleg8=8, @SuaraCaleg8=800 COMMIT`.  Does it help, to use that EXEC format, w/ *ALL* parms?

Comment: Why do you have so many `SELECT Id FROM Kelurahans WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat` statements everywhere?  Are they just for debugging or do they have a functional purpose?

Comment: In your question, when you say `description:  1. number 1 on the first letter...`, I suspect you are mis-using the word `letter`.  Do you mean `parameter`?  It's also not clear what you mean, there, by the word `character`.  In that `description` section, can you give examples for each point?  (Can you give an example for 1, an example for 2, an example for 3, and so on...?)

Comment: sorry my mistake,it should be a parameter not the letter 
example: 
BEGIN TRANSACTION COMMIT updatesms EXEC 1,1,1,300,1,80,2,30,3,70,4,50,5,60,6,50,7,25,8,800 
In the above examples when I enter the number 1 in the parameter @ KodeTingkat,all went very well,but when i try to enter the numbers 2 and 3 on @ KodeTingkat parameters, stored procedure does not work.

Examples of parameters @ KodeTingkat = 2: 
BEGIN TRANSACTION COMMIT updatesms EXEC 2,1,1,300,1,80,2,30,3,70,4,50,5,60,6,50,7,25,8,800 
Examples of parameters @ KodeTingkat = 3: 
2,1,1,300,1,80,2,30,3,70,4,50,5,60,6,50,7,25,8,800 COMMIT

Comment: Thanks for the response, and the examples; I've posted my reply as an answer.  (Please note, regarding comments:  if you are commenting in ***reply*** to someone who asked a question, begin your comment with `@` and their logon [for example `@Doug_Ivison`], so your reply comment will go **immediately** to their INBOX:  they will see it sooner, and, they will even see it if they otherwise were not coming back to this question page.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your last comment... it answered a few of our questions.  Based on your usage and your columnNames / tableNames, I'm guessing English is not your first language... please forgive me if, in trying to make my English easy to understand, I used too many words.  (I wonder if [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com) might be helpful with my reply.)

My first note is that parameter `@KodeTingkat` is *NOT* controlling any other part of the code... its value is not used in any `IF`, nor in any `UPDATE` command's `SET` or `WHERE`.

The stored procedure's repeated reference to `@KodeTingkat`, in the code below, would not affect any `IF` or `UPDATE`, but could return ***resultsets*** when the stored procedure is called:

```
    SELECT Id
        FROM Kelurahans
        WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
```

Since this is not affecting any `IF` or `UPDATE`, I'm guessing your basic concern -- `when i try to enter the numbers 2 and 3 on @ KodeTingkat parameters, stored procedure does not work` (words from your last comment) -- is probably due to a ***logic problem***.

Which brings us back to RBarryYoung's question:  what's the purpose of that code above?  If you want to *use* the value returned, you might want to do the below:

```
    DECLARE @Kelurahans_ID INT
    SELECT @Kelurahans_ID = Id
        FROM Kelurahans
        WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
```

... and then use the value of @Kelurahans_ID in `IF` statements, `SET` clauses, or `WHERE` clauses.

And in general, while checking for a logic problem... you might start by using Vladimir Oselsky's suggestion, of passing your parameters `by reference`.

Examples, where only the first parameter value is changed:

> EXEC updatesms @KodeTingkat=1, @KodeKel=1, @KodeTPS=1, @SuaraPartai=300, @KodeCaleg1=1, @SuaraCaleg1=80, @KodeCaleg2=2, @SuaraCaleg2=30, @KodeCaleg3=3, @SuaraCaleg3=70, @KodeCaleg4=4, @SuaraCaleg4=50, @KodeCaleg5=5, @SuaraCaleg5=60, @KodeCaleg6=6, @SuaraCaleg6=50, @KodeCaleg7=7, @SuaraCaleg7=25, @KodeCaleg8=8, @SuaraCaleg8=800
>
> EXEC updatesms @KodeTingkat=2, @KodeKel=1, @KodeTPS=1, @SuaraPartai=300, @KodeCaleg1=1, @SuaraCaleg1=80, @KodeCaleg2=2, @SuaraCaleg2=30, @KodeCaleg3=3, @SuaraCaleg3=70, @KodeCaleg4=4, @SuaraCaleg4=50, @KodeCaleg5=5, @SuaraCaleg5=60, @KodeCaleg6=6, @SuaraCaleg6=50, @KodeCaleg7=7, @SuaraCaleg7=25, @KodeCaleg8=8, @SuaraCaleg8=800
>
> EXEC updatesms @KodeTingkat=3, @KodeKel=1, @KodeTPS=1, @SuaraPartai=300, @KodeCaleg1=1, @SuaraCaleg1=80, @KodeCaleg2=2, @SuaraCaleg2=30, @KodeCaleg3=3, @SuaraCaleg3=70, @KodeCaleg4=4, @SuaraCaleg4=50, @KodeCaleg5=5, @SuaraCaleg5=60, @KodeCaleg6=6, @SuaraCaleg6=50, @KodeCaleg7=7, @SuaraCaleg7=25, @KodeCaleg8=8, @SuaraCaleg8=800

Why this might help, in debugging:  it simply makes it easy to see what parameter values you are passing, and easy to check whether they are the values you intend.

In building the above examples, the first thing I noticed is that you are passing *20 parameters*, instead of *26 parameters*.  I realize you're allowed to do that -- not a logic problem -- because of the default values assigned in your stored procedure.  Just be aware that, in your `EXEC` examples, there are no values for the following parameters:  @KodeCaleg9, @SuaraCaleg9, @KodeCaleg10, @SuaraCaleg10, @KodeCaleg11, and @SuaraCaleg11.  And, looking at your `IF` commands, that means there will not be any updates based on those parameters.

Also, you are currently passing `@SuaraCaleg8=800`, instead of passing `@SuaraCaleg11=800`.  Is that what you want?

I hope that helps...

**UPDATE:**

At your `pastebin` link, you asked (1) Where to put the `DEFINE` and `SELECT` for variable `@Kelurahans_ID`, and (2) Where to use that variable in the update.

Answers: 
 
(1) To begin with, you could simply put the `DECLARE` near the top of the stored procedure.  Then, at each occurrence of `SELECT Id FROM Kelurahans WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat`, just replace `SELECT Id`, with `SELECT @Kelurahans_ID = Id`.

(2) You would use `@Kelurahans_ID` to select a column within table `[TPSSet]`.  You tell us:  ***is*** there such a matching column?  And guessing, is it `[TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan]`?  If so, then you would add a line to the `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE`:  `AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID`.

**UPDATE 2:** 
 
Responding to your comment:  I see what you put at http://pastebin.com/KiQWNDFU -- thanks -- and...
 
1) Please answer the very first comment, posted by `KM.`:  what do "SP working" and "SP not working" mean?  Is it just "not updating"?  Or are you also getting an error message, in which case *what error message*?

2) Please answer my question:  Are you clear that `[TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan]` is the column that is *INTENDED* to match `@Kelurahans_ID`?

3) To debug this, try executing it outside the stored procedure -- in a normal query window -- using `PRINT` commands to show whether all the `UPDATE` steps are being executed, and how many rows are being updated in each step.

The example code below makes the `ALTER PROCEDURE` command into a `DECLARE` command, adds `SET` commands to match your parameter values passed, and adds `PRINT` commands to trace what happens.  Just try it three times, with different values for `@KodeTingkat`, and let us know what happens:

```
------    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updatesms]

DECLARE
        @KodeTingkat INT,
        @KodeKel INT,
        @KodeTPS INT,
        @SuaraPartai INT,
        @KodeCaleg1 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg1 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg2 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg2 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg3 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg3 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg4 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg4 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg5 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg5 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg6 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg6 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg7 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg7 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg8 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg8 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg9 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg9 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg10 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg10 INT = -1,
        @KodeCaleg11 INT = -1,
        @SuaraCaleg11 INT = -1

------        AS


SET @KodeTingkat=1 
----SET @KodeTingkat=2 
----SET @KodeTingkat=3 

SET @KodeKel=1
SET @KodeTPS=1
SET @SuaraPartai=300
SET @KodeCaleg1=1
SET @SuaraCaleg1=80
SET @KodeCaleg2=2
SET @SuaraCaleg2=30
SET @KodeCaleg3=3
SET @SuaraCaleg3=70
SET @KodeCaleg4=4
SET @SuaraCaleg4=50
SET @KodeCaleg5=5
SET @SuaraCaleg5=60
SET @KodeCaleg6=6
SET @SuaraCaleg6=50
SET @KodeCaleg7=7
SET @SuaraCaleg7=25
SET @KodeCaleg8=8
SET @SuaraCaleg8=800 

BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        -- suara partai
        DECLARE @Kelurahans_ID INT

        SELECT @Kelurahans_ID = Id
        FROM Kelurahans
        WHERE Kelurahan_Tingkatan = @KodeTingkat
        ;
        PRINT 'A)  @Kelurahans_ID is set to ' + STR(@Kelurahans_ID) + ', reading ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'

        UPDATE TPSSet SET SuaraPartai=@SuaraPartai
        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS
        ;
        PRINT 'B)  SuaraPartai is set to ' + STR(@SuaraPartai) + ', reading ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'

        -- suara caleg 1
        IF @KodeCaleg1 > 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'C)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg1, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg1) 
                ;
                UPDATE Calegs
                SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg1
                WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg1
                AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                        SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID
                )
                ;
                PRINT 'D)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg1, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg1) + '; processing ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'
        END
        -- suara caleg 2
        IF @KodeCaleg2 > 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'E)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg2, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg2) 
                ;
                UPDATE Calegs
                SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg2
                WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg2
                AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                        SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID
                )
                ;
                PRINT 'F)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg2, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg2) + '; processing ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'
        END
-- suara caleg 3
        IF @KodeCaleg3 > 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'G)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg3, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg3) 
                ;
                UPDATE Calegs
                SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg3
                WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg3
                AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                        SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID
                )
                ;
                PRINT 'H)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg3, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg3) + '; processing ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'
        END
-- suara caleg 4
        IF @KodeCaleg4 > 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'I)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg4, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg4) 
                ;
                UPDATE Calegs
                SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg4
                WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg4
                AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                        SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID
                )
                ;
                PRINT 'J)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg4, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg4) + '; processing ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'
        END
-- suara caleg 5
        IF @KodeCaleg5 > 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'K)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg5, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg5) 
                ;
                UPDATE Calegs
                SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg5
                WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg5
                AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                        SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID
                )
                ;
                PRINT 'L)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg5, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg5) + '; processing ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'
        END
-- suara caleg 6
        IF @KodeCaleg6 > 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'M)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg6, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg6) 
                ;
                UPDATE Calegs
                SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg6
                WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg6
                AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                        SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID
                )
                ;
                PRINT 'N)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg6, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg6) + '; processing ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'
        END
-- suara caleg 7
        IF @KodeCaleg7 > 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'O)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg7, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg7) 
                ;
                UPDATE Calegs
                SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg7
                WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg7
                AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                        SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID
                )
                ;
                PRINT 'P)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg7, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg7) + '; processing ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'
        END
-- suara caleg 8
        IF @KodeCaleg8 > 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'Q)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg8, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg8) 
                ;
                UPDATE Calegs
                SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg8
                WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg8
                AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                        SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID
                )
                ;
                PRINT 'R)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg8, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg8) + '; processing ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'
        END    
-- suara caleg 9
        IF @KodeCaleg9 > 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'S)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg9, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg9) 
                ;
                UPDATE Calegs
                SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg9
                WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg9
                AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                        SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID
                )
                ;
                PRINT 'T)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg9, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg9) + '; processing ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'
        END
-- suara caleg 10
        IF @KodeCaleg10 > 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'U)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg10, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg10) 
                ;
                UPDATE Calegs
                SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg10
                WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg10
                AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                        SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID
                )
                ;
                PRINT 'V)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg10, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg10) + '; processing ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'
        END    
-- suara caleg 11
        IF @KodeCaleg11 > 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT 'W)  Just before update of Calegs, for Code=@KodeCaleg11, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg11) 
                ;
                UPDATE Calegs
                SET JumlahPerolehan=@SuaraCaleg11
                WHERE Code = @KodeCaleg11
                AND Caleg_TPS IN (
                        SELECT id FROM TPSSet
                        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = @KodeKel AND TPSS = @KodeTPS AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = @Kelurahans_ID
                )
                ;
                PRINT 'X)  Updated Calegs for Code=@KodeCaleg11, which = ' + STR(@KodeCaleg11) + '; processing ' + STR(@@rowcount) + ' rows.'
        END            
END
```

Hope that helps...

**UPDATE 3:**

The number of rows it is updating, comes from the number of rows it is SELECTing. 
Does it make sense, then, that this would return 1 row...

```
SELECT *
FROM Calegs
WHERE Code = 1        --THE VALUE OF @KodeCaleg1
AND Caleg_TPS IN (
        SELECT id 
        FROM TPSSet
        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = 1  --THE VALUE OF @KodeKel 
          AND TPSS = 1      --THE VALUE OF @KodeTPS 
          AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = 1      --THE VALUE OF @Kelurahans_ID
    )
```

... while this returns 0 rows?

```
SELECT *
FROM Calegs
WHERE Code = 1        --THE VALUE OF @KodeCaleg1
AND Caleg_TPS IN (
        SELECT id 
        FROM TPSSet
        WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = 1  --THE VALUE OF @KodeKel 
          AND TPSS = 1      --THE VALUE OF @KodeTPS 
          AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = 2      --THE VALUE OF @Kelurahans_ID
    )
```

Or -- a related question -- consider the sub-queries, by themselves: 
What does this SELECT return?

```
SELECT id 
FROM TPSSet
WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = 1  --THE VALUE OF @KodeKel 
    AND TPSS = 1        --THE VALUE OF @KodeTPS 
    AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = 1        --THE VALUE OF @Kelurahans_ID
```

and what does this SELECT return?

```
SELECT id 
FROM TPSSet
WHERE TPS_Kelurahan = 1  --THE VALUE OF @KodeKel 
    AND TPSS = 1        --THE VALUE OF @KodeTPS 
    AND [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] = 2        --THE VALUE OF @Kelurahans_ID
```

Comment: :forgive me, i'm use google translate for my Quetion... :)
my english language so bad..thanks for answer..but i'm not understand with your command..so you can see my quetion on this link : http://pastebin.com/KiQWNDFU

Comment: @olipiskandar No problem... I added those questions, as an **UPDATE** to your question, and I'll add my response now, as an **UPDATE** to my answer.

Comment: @olipiskandar Somebody rejected my edit, which added your pastebin text to your question.  So, instead, I mentioned those follow-up questions in my answer.  (Since websites like pastebin can change or even go away, we're encouraged to keep the dialog here, on StackOverflow.)  So, the first question, which I put in my answer and which you could answer in a comment, is:  does `[TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan]` equal `[Kelurahans].[Id]`?  The second question (only in this comment), is:  could `[Kelurahans].[Id]` change, while the stored procedure is running?

Comment: i'have been update My Stored Procedure like you want On http://pastebin.com/KiQWNDFU, but still not working if i put @KodeTingkat=2 or @KodeTingkat=3

Comment: @olipiskandar I've updated my answer, showing example code you could use, to "trace" what's happening.  Please answer KM.'s question (1), my question (2), and let us know the results of (3).  HTH! (hope that helps :)

Comment: my answer 
--1. stored procedure does not work when KodeTingkat = 2 or KodeTingkat = 3. automatically, each table associated with the table Tingkatans not perform the update. 
--2. yes, so [TPSSet].[TPS_Kelurahan] match Kelurahans_ID 
--3. I've included the output on my question above

Comment: @olipiskandar I guess you're also saying that you're *not* getting error messages.  In any case, I've posted an ***UPDATE 3:*** to my answer, in response to the test output.  (Aside, note:  I moved your last response to the END of the question, as an UPDATE, because overwriting the original question made the comment-history (and the beginning of my answer) no longer make sense.)

Comment: @olipiskandar Oooops... I missed one variable in my UPDATE 3:  I meant to put hard-coded values in, for all variables, (so all the SELECTs could run in a new window, without variable declarations).  For that reason, I've now hardcoded a value, where `@KodeCaleg1` was.

Comment: Thanks, @olipiskandar, for the "accept as answer"... and, for the sake of anyone finding this StackOverflow question... could you say a little bit about what you finally discovered was the resolution?  (1) What were the results of those `SELECT`s above, in "UPDATE 3"?  (2) Did the resolution involve (2a) a *code change*, or a (2b) *data fix*... or did it turn out to be (2c) correctly operating, and you simply came to understand why?  For a longer reply, with details, you could ***add to the end*** of your question, as an "UPDATE 2" or "FINAL UPDATE", or "RESOLUTION:".  Thanks...